# Load Balancer $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] Not working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've switched to using an Amazon AWS Elastic Load Balancer and now I'm getting a private IP address for `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` - which used to give me the client's IP address.

**How do I get the clients IP address now?**

Comment: If the Load Balancer doesn't set a header with the client's IP adress, then you won't be able to get the client's IP adress. You might to take a look at the `$_SERVER` superglobal and look if there is such a header (e.g. called `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`).

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/x-forwarded-headers.html

Comment: Apache, nginx, or other? Each has a way of getting the X-Forwarded-For address and using it.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois so I can use $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];? :)

Comment: If it is set (should be as the AWS documentation suggests that it gets sent), sure.

Comment: Charlotte's right. You should write that as an answer.

Comment: Just uploading the new version to my load balancer - will test out to see if it works - you should definitely write this as an answer Charlotte :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your webserver receives HTTP requests from the Amazon ELB. Therefore, the remote address will always be one of the ELB ip addresses.
If you need the remote host's address from behind the ELB, get it from HTTP header "X-Forwarded-For".

Comment: X-Forwarded-For is returning this: "192.155.96.40, 54.240.144.13" - any idea why it is returning two addresses and what they are?

Comment: Yes, you probably need the first address. 

The ELB can return multiple addresses, as explained on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/x-forwarded-headers.html:

If a request goes through multiple proxies, the clientIPAddress in the X-Forwarded-For request header is followed by the IP addresses of each successive proxy that the request goes through before it reaches your load balancer. Therefore, the right-most IP address is the IP address of the most recent proxy and the left-most IP address is the IP address of the originating client.

Comment: Hmmm true but I think I am only going to trust the rightmost one. I don't trust anything from the client side really....

Comment: Correction - the right one is Amazon IP still - so yes, the leftmost one I think :)

Answer (score 2):

The below works for me in httpd.conf global section where the LogFormat is defined.  With the change below, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will be set to the client ip on php-fpm and not the ELB ip.

```
<IfModule remoteip_module>
   RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
   LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
   LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
</IfModule>
```

Solution is from https://medium.com/@jiraknet/apache-2-4-mod-remoteip-for-get-real-ip-on-aws-elb-6e9f40876b06

Comment: this is actually a good and simple solution, call it a "hack" if you want but is simple and clean, the only downside is that you lose the proxy ip forwarding the request, if you are not making use of it you can definitely use this solution